# Compare/Intersection List of Lists

Tags: common-lisp

I wanted to use [`intersection`](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#intersection-of-lists)
to see the intersection of two lists.

While

```
(intersection (list 1 1) (list 1 1))
```

works perfectly fine and returns `(1 1)`,

```
 (intersection (list (list 1 2) (list 1 4)) (list (list 1 2) (list 1 5)))
```

doesnt return me (1 2) but NIL.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language that you are using

Comment: but i used the flag "common-lisp" ?^^

Comment: Don't worry about it. The tag looks fine to me. It's possible Nicolas overlooked that tag and/or didn't know "Common Lisp" was the name of a particular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`intersection`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_isec_.htm) takes an optional `:test` keyword argument to specify what definition of "equality" to use. The default is [`eql`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm#eql), which compares lists for pointer equality. Since your two lists are actually distinct lists in memory, they're not `eql`. Use [`equal`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm#eql) to compare lists element-wise.

```
  (intersection (list (list 1 2) (list 1 4)) (list (list 1 2) (list 1 5)) :test #'equal)
```

Comment: Short and simple. Thank you for the explanation!